# IE Mobile conditional comment is read by ie8 and lower

Tags: internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, conditional-comments, ie-mobile

I am developing a responsive site and do use media queries, which are not read by IE8 as well as the internet explorer on windows phone. Therefore I am using conditional comments for these. For IE8 and lower I use the following snippet to include the screen css:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
...some stylesheets...
<![endif]-->
```

For windows phone I have to include the css for the mobile resolution and I am using the following snippet:

```
<!--[if IEMobile]> 
...some stylesheets...
<![endif]-->
```

My problem is that the IE 8 seems to use the stylesheets inside the conditional comment for IE mobile as well, because as soon as I am including the styles inside the conditional comment for IE Mobile, the whole site in IE8 and below crashes.

I also tried this combination:

```
<!--[if (IEMobile)&!(lt IE 9)]>
```

But without success. Maybe the idea of the combination is right and I am just making a mistake with the syntax or there is some problem with the IE8 and the rather new conditional comment regarding IE Mobile?

Comment: For all with this problem: I could not solve it! Just changed everything in a way I did not need css only for windows mobile.

Answer (score 2):

According to this: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/html/ie-conditional-comments.html

You should be able to use this syntax for combining conditions:

```
<!--[if IEMobile]><![if gt IE 8]> Yo IE 9+ on mobiles <![endif]><![endif]-->
```